# How to have a UITableView in a popup Subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a MainWindowViewController with the proper protocols. I also have the dataSouce methods implemented in MainWindowViewController.

```
@interface MainWindowController : UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UAModalPanelDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

I have the delegate and dataSource set in the `viewDidLoad` of MainWindowViewController.

```
self.friendsTableView.delegate = self;
self.friendsTableView.dataSource = self;
```

What should happen is that I press the friends button. A xib file name FriendsPopUpView_iPhone is loaded and it should bring up a `UITableView` of friends. But the friendsPopUpView's tableview shows up with empty rows. What am I doing wrong?

FriendsPopUpView_iPhone.xib contains a `UITableView`.
friendsTableView is an outlet from the tableview created in FriendsPopUpView_iPhone.xib.
friendsPopUpView is  a `UIView` outlet for the the view in FriendsPopUpView_iPhone.xib.
Here is the action connected to the friend button on the main MainWindowController.

```
- (IBAction)on_friends:(id)sender {
    if (self.friendsPopUpView == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FriendsPopUpView_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:self.friendsPopUpView];

        UIButton* clickedButton = (UIButton*) sender;
        CGRect sFrame = CGRectMake(clickedButton.frame.origin.x-100, clickedButton.frame.origin.y,
                                   self.friendsPopUpView.frame.size.width,
                                   self.friendsPopUpView.frame.size.height);
        self.friendsPopUpView.frame = sFrame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the popup view nib contain hooked up outlets to the MainWindowViewController class (like self.friendsPopUpView)?  It must in order for anything to work.

You can't set the delegate and datasource before the table view exists.  It doesn't exist when the MainWindowViewController viewDidLoad fires.  To setup the delegate and datasource in code, do it after the nib is loaded, once the table exists.

If you setup the other outlets (like the friendsPopUp and the friendsTableView) as nib outlets (connected to the "file's owner" which you would have set as MainWindowViewController) then you can set the delegate and datasource the same way, no code required.  Otherwise, do it in code after you load the nib...

```
- (IBAction)on_friends:(id)sender {
    if (self.friendsPopUpView == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FriendsPopUpView_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];

    // assuming you have a friendsPopUpView outlet setup in the nib
    // also assuming you have a friendsTableView outlet setup in the nib, both of these connected

    // now this will work
    self.friendsTableView.delegate = self;
    self.friendsTableView.dataSource = self;
```